# MacBook Pro 11,1 Magsafe connector gets hot

Tags: 14.04, kernel, power-management, battery

I've installed Ubuntu 14.04 on my Macbook Pro 11,1 and updated the kernel to version 3.19.8. I have a problem now.
If I plug in the Magsafe connector the connector and the surroundings on the macbook gets very hot. I don't know why. With the old kernel 3.13, I don't detect this problem. Any ideas? Any proposed solutions for this issue?

Thanks everybody for help.